# Multi Touch problem in Custom UiTableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, uitouch

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
AssignmentTableCell *cell = (AssignmentTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AssignmentTableCell" owner:self options:Nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Here is my Code for custom Cell initialization. I am detecting uitouch for custom cells and then i am pushing view controller rather than using DidSelected Event of the UItableView. But problem i am facing is

I can select 2 rows at a time, which is not my intension and that leads to application crash. I have tried to disable multitouch but of no use. they still keep selecting 2 cells at a time.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Edit 1:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    imgBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rowSelected.png"];
    [[self delegate] touchStarted:tag];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    imgBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7CustomCellBackground.png"];
    [[self delegate] touchEnded:tag];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //imgBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7CustomCellBackground.png"];
    [[self delegate] rowTocuchedFromClicked:tag];
}
```

Here are the touches method of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add some code regarding how you are detecting touches on the cell? Also, the reason you are seeing multiple selections in because you are not de-selecting the selected cell. Do something like-

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated: YES];
    //your other stuff
}
```

The reason for the crash is something else, which can only be ascertained after you paste the console logs.

Comment: I don't think you need to detect touches on your cell like this. If you have multiple subviews in your custom cell, you should be adding targets to them, using `addTarget:action:forControlEvents`. You have still not pasted the crash log. Does the multiple selection work after my suggestion?

Comment: actually crash logs are nothing but when you touch two rows at the same time, Navigation controller gives error that you cant push two at one time.

Comment: Are you touching 2 rows simultaneously using 2 fingers? If yes, then this crash is occurring because of your custom touch detection. If you rely on the default table view detection, this crash won't occur.

Comment: but i need custom cell touch as well. how can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need custom cell touch? I am under the impression that you must be having multiple subcomponents in the cell, such as buttons, images, etc., tapping on which should cause something. If I am correct, then you do not need custom cell touch.

Comment: i want to change cell image background on touch start and touch end. so i dont know anyother way how to do this. can you please guide me in this. thanks

Comment: By touch-start & touch-end, do you mean a finger is being dragged? Horizontally or vertically?

Comment: no not necessarily dragged but just i want to detect if the finger has touched the cell so that i could change image. draging i dont need neither its direction.

Comment: @Akshay let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2801/discussion-between-chsab420-and-akshay)